# Open SQL Light DB from Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, sqlite

I have installed `sqlitebrowser` to browse database. But when I try to open db from Unity I have only one option `Open with gedit`

[image]

When I choose open `With Other Application...` I cant find `sqlitebrowser`. How to setup system to open db in fast way with double click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` from your home directory, and add this line:

```
application/x-sqlite3=sqlitebrowser.desktop
```

Close the file. Now, SQLite3 databases should automatically open with `sqlitebrowser`.